# What is the name of this space game?

Tags: game-identification

Gameplay is just like [Star Citizen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3l-epO6oUHE)'s where there's a crew in every spaceship and everyone has their own role.
Some images:

[image: picture 1]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found the answer, it's [Pulsar: the lost colony](http://www.pulsarthegame.com/)